# Touches on the far left side not registering due to 3D Touch App Switching

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, touchscreen, 3dtouch

Since iPhone6s, when Apple introduced 3D Touch, they added a new way to switch apps : press down on the side of the screen, and swipe.

An annoying side effect is that this has introduced a small "dead zone" on the far left side of the screen. This can lead to missed input, which makes a game that we're developing feel bugged. The user is actually touching the screen, but because he touches the side, nothing happens.

I've seen this happen in both Unity and buildbox (cocos) games. In single tap games, this is not really an issue, but in our upcoming game, the user has to press on the left and right sides of the screen with their thumbs, and it happens quite a lot that a touch doesn't register.

Is there any way to turn off this behaviour in a game?

EDIT : As requested, here's the code I use :

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
    if (Input.mousePosition.x < Screen.width / 2f) {
        leftDown = true;
    } else {
        rightDown = true;
    }
}
```

This is called in Update, and the leftDown/rightDown variables are used in FixedUpdate.

I've also tried looping through touches, same result :

```
for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++) {
    if (Input.touches [i].position.x < Screen.width / 2f) {
        leftDown = true;
    } else {
        rightDown = true;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What code do you use to detect the touch? Please post that and which function you are callling the code from. Also mention your Unity version.

Comment: Added the code to the question. As for Unity version : 5.5.0f3, but it was present in older versions too. This is not a code bug, but it's new iOS behaviour, which I hope I can turn off for our game.

Comment: Almost there. You missed a part of my question. Where are you call that code in your question from?

Comment: This is called in Update, and the leftDown/rightDown variables are used in FixedUpdate.

Comment: You should be using `Input.touches` not `Input.GetMouseButton`. You said you tried that in your question. Can you also post the `Input.touches` code you tried but doesn't work? I have a solution but want to make sure it's not something yo have tried before.

Comment: Added to the question too.

Comment: Almost the-same thing I had. Try [this](http://pastebin.com/fbhaU7sS). If that does not work, go to Help->Report a Bug... and tell Unity your problem because this looks like a bug.

Comment: It's not a Unity bug. As I stated, it's new iOS behaviour that affects non-Unity games as well. All I can hope for is that there's a way to turn it off, hidden somewhere in XCode.

Comment: I know that from your question. Forgot to finish my sentence. If you report it to Unity and mention the iOS version, Unity will report it to Apple and Apple will fix it. I've seen that happen before between these two companies. It won't be fixed if you ignore it unless there are other people that file for a bug report on this problem.